# Django Photologue Tutorial

Tags: django, photologue

I have a hard time understanding how photologue works exactly.
Is anybody aware of a Example Project Tutorial where I can display a gallery via Django-Photologue. Where Imagelinks are stored in a database?

Or how can I achieve that in Django?
Or what else is out there to create a decent Photo Display?

Thanks for the time!

Comment: What exactly are you asking for? Are you asking for a step by step tutorial to setting up photologue or are you wanting to know how it works?

Comment: The [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/django-photologue/wiki/ReadMe) seems to be OK. In which part you can't go on? What is a ImageLink? I can't found that neither in the code nor the docs.

Answer (score 9):

The best way to get started with photologue is to start a new django project, and follow the [installation instructions](http://code.google.com/p/django-photologue/wiki/ReadMe).  Then, load up the django admin and start adding photos and creating galleries.  You should be able to get a good understanding of Photologue that way.

Photologue is based around the concept of having gallerys of images with different photo sizes and effects.  It's great if you want to show a gallery of images.  If you are looking to intergrate images into your own apps, you might find **[ImageKit](https://github.com/jdriscoll/django-imagekit)** much more useful.  I think it's based on Photologue, but instead of giving you automated photo galleries it provides hooks that you can use to do manage photos programmatically.

Comment: Quoting the author let me add this: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/django-photologue/Gq0bsvx3AIw/HzEgPHlRgbUJ

Comment: With code.google.com shutting down, I found a more up-to-date version of the installation instructions here: http://django-photologue.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pages/installation.html

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example project by the author of photologue:

https://github.com/jdriscoll/django-photologue/tree/master/example_project